# Draw the graphical model for the distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, independence

I would like to draw the graphical model for the distribution in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4499789/a-perp-kern-5pt-perp-b-b-perp-kern-5pt-perp-c-c-perp-kern-5pt-perp-a-but?noredirect=1#comment9442912_4499789) and capture as many independence assumption as possible. The distribution is:

> Let $A = \{\text{flipping coin A}\}$ and $B\{\text{flipping coin B}\}$ and  $C = \begin{cases} 1 &  \text{both heads or both tails} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$. So this means that $A \perp\kern-5pt\perp B ,B \perp\kern-5pt\perp C, C \perp\kern-5pt\perp A $ but $A$ and $B$ are not conditionally independent when given $C$

So, would the following graphical model (belief network) be an accurate representation?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is correct. Notice that conditioning on $C$ provides some information about the result of $A$ and $B$. In fact, if $C=1$, then $A=B$, otherwise $A \neq B$, so of course $A$ and $B$ are not independent conditioned on $C$.

The information you're capturing in this graphical model is: $A$ and $B$ are independent and $C$ is constant when conditioning on $A$ and $B$.

Comment: can i also state that $A \perp\kern-5pt\perp C$ and $B \perp\kern-5pt\perp C$?

Comment: That's correct. Also see the answer to this question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/489203/why-cant-bayesian-and-markov-networks-represent-all-conditional-independencies